# Is it possible to emit an error with NgRx createSelector?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

May be there is a different way to solve it (like create another selector especially for errors)

```
    export const getMSFState = createFeatureSelector<STState>('st');
    export const selectCreatedSensor = createSelector(
        getMSFState,
        selectAllSensors,
        (state: STState, sensorArray: SeasonTotals[], props: { blockId: number}) => {
            const isSuccessCreate = state.action === fromST.ST_ADD_ELEMENT && !state.loading && !state.error;
            const isAnErrorCreate = state.action === fromST.ST_ADD_ELEMENT && !state.loading && state.error;
            if (isAnErrorCreate) {
                return throwError('Error X');
            }
            const blockSensors = [...sensorArray].filter(s => s.blockId = props.blockId);
            return isSuccessCreate ? blockSensors.pop() : null;
        }
    );
```

*I want to catch the second subscribe parameter* (the error one), but I don't know if is possible to emit it in the NgRx selector

```
    this.store.pipe(
        select(STSelectors.selectCreatedSensor, { blockId: this.id })
    ).subscribe((data) =>  {
        console.log('success creation', data);
    }, (error) => {
        // I can't catch this, instead I catch it in the first subscribe parameter (in the success one)
        // And the value emited is an Observable object
        console.log('something went wrong', error); 
    })
```

Comment: We're going to need more details. Exactly what do you want to happen?

Comment: nope this is not possible a `selector` does not return an observable it always returns a value, therefore you cannot use `throwError`

Comment: Thanks @Nickolaus, so what do you recomend to do as an alternative?. Maybe create another selector for catch errors?

Comment: ... it would be intresting what happens if you `return new Error('xxx')` instead of `throwError`

Comment: My advice would be to create an error property and use your reducer to fill that property if X condition has been achieved.
If you need to do this across state (Combining different parts of state) then use an effect to update the reducer.

Answer (score 3):

Selectors are pure functions, I find it a  bad practice to throw errors in selectors (and reducers). You should instead return a value (`null`, `undefined`, empty object, ...).

Comment: What would you do in the case you had logic you wished to re-use in a selector, such as a function that does conversion but this logic could throw an Error, and then the selector could catch the Error so there is no side effect in order to return a default value such as your suggestion. Here it may be a desire to log the error using a service (but also services are not injectable in selectors AFAIK), but of course then its not a pure function. Is there any advice on how to transform this kind of case to be pure?

Sorry if I'm hijacking the original question... I can open another if need be.

Comment: Further to the above, I can imagine that instead of throwing an Error, using a return type to indicate an error, similar to an Optional / Maybe pattern in pattern matched /  functional languages could be useful, and then instead of try/catch, its a matter of selecting the value or a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are always returning partial information about the current `state` of the `store` not a `stream`.

`throwError` returns an error to an `observable` stream and so you cannot return an actual state.

... basically what will happen is you will get something like `Observable<Observable<Error>>` when the `throwError` function in the selector returns, therefore this will not work.

...

First: You are using the store wrong, you should:

- dispatch a `getData` event
- in case of error: an `getDataError` event
- in case of success an `getDataSuccess` event

My approach would be creating an exclusive `loadingSelector` `loadedSelector` and `errorSelector` wrap the data-loading in a `service` or `facade` or whatever you want to call it and do the error handling there so you can subscribe properly in your components:

```js
getData(): Observable<MyData> {
   return this.store.select(selector.loaded)
     .pipe(
       switchMap(loaded => {
          if (loaded) {
             return this.store.select(selector.myData);  // if data already loaded return it
          }
          this.store.dispatch(loadingAction);  // dispatch loading event
          return this.store.select(selector.loading) // select the loading state
       })
       filter(loading => !loading), // wait until loading changes to false
       switchMapTo(this.store.select(selector.error)), // get current error state
       switchMap(error => { 
          if (error) {
            return throwError(error); // throw error if exits
          }
          return this.store.select(selector.myData); // otherwise return data
       })
     }
}
```